# CORS Client-Side vs Server-Side

Tags: javascript, web, cors

I am currently working on a simple React app whose only job is to fetch some data from a JSON endpoint, return it and render it onto the screen. I am using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) to make the client-side requests. I have a couple of different scenarios I was hoping the community could help me distill.

If I make a request from my application to an endpoint hosted on [JSONPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/), it:

1. Allows me to do so
2. Sets the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header (presumably based off of the `Origin` request header)

All is good with the above. Similarly, if I make a request to an endpoint hosted on an S3 bucket (which frankly, I am not sure of the access control), I am unable to do it due to CORS (again, presumably because of the aforementioned access control set on the resource).

When I move over to a Node application and instead use something like [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) I *am* able to make the request, no problem.

I understand that this is a browser level protection but I was reading an article here earlier that mentioned how it could protect a website from a DDoS attack if multiple, cross-origin requests being run which load a site.

I sort of understood this but what is preventing me from doing the same if I spin up some machines and have them all run some Node.js code that also execute many `GET` requests against some server?

Also, is *any* CORS protected issue bypassed by simply making the call from a server?

Answer (score 2):

If you are building an API and don't want everybody to be able to access that API then the first thing is to add CORS rules. But this only protects against API calls made from a browser. In order to protect your API properly you will have to implement RATE LIMITING, Access Control with API Keys, JWTs, Client IDs/Secrets.

> Also, is any CORS protected issue bypassed by simply making the call from a server?

CORS rules are enforced by the browser, so if you make an API call from a Web Server or from an application like Postman/SOAPAPI/etc there will not be any CORS rules enforced.

Comment: Apparently the question was not good enough but thank you for this answer! It makes more sense to me now.